# insert date from jquery datepicker to oracle database

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to insert date from jquery datepicker to database.

```
String startDate = request.getParameter("datepicker");
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date tempDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDate);
        SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MM-YYYY");
        out.println("Output date is = " + outputDateFormat.format(tempDate));
```

i'm using `ps.setDate(1,***)`, here i'm unable to understand how to convert `tempDate` to sqldate and place it in `***` place above and finally insert it into database.

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(tempDate.getTime()));
```